# jQuery not work on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my jQuery :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.popup', function() {
     var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=800,width=800');
     if (window.focus)
     {
        NWin.focus();
     }
     return false;     
});
```

Work on Firefox, but nor working on chrome.

Comment: Have you check the console for errors?

Comment: Maybe Chrome has blocked the popup.

Comment: press f12 while in your page and there you will see what's the x in your script

Comment: No erros on my console.
Popup are allowed by my chrome.

Comment: Try debugging it by adding `debugger;` before the  if statement. see if `window.open` works correnctly.

Comment: I put "alert" : 
when my page is loaded ->Works
when click -> Not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, try give a look to your code to find differences

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.popup', function() {
     var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=800,width=800');
     return false;     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906074/jquery-not-work-on-chrome#" class="popup">Site</a>
```

PS: Inside the snippet it can't open popup but i tried it out and it works

Comment: Your exemple not works for me :     "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null"

Comment: The same ! i dont understand why.. There is no error

Comment: What's happening when you use it now?

Comment: Does it open? Or nothing happen?

Comment: I found why .... My "popup" class exist on firefox but doesnt exist on chrome .... I have to find why now. I'll keep you informed. Thanks for your help

Comment: Np if i helped you can upvote or mark the answer ^^ if the class isn't important you can bind the event on a instead of a.popup

Comment: i upvote your answer :) it work now 
I had :
    if($_GET['leftmenu'] == "thirdparties"){
                 $link.=' class="popup classfortooltip"';
                }
                else{
                 $link.=' class="classfortooltip"';
                }

And i added "popup" on my else. I dont indersstand why chrome didnt understand my "if".

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").on("click",function(){
          window.open("https://www.google.co.in","Test window","width=200,height=100");
        });
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LhmqVsiPohjpkEiHbe5Z?p=preview)